# How To Pass a Ref to a SVG Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a svg component that is declared like so:

```js
import {ReactComponent as Icon} from 'someplace.svg'

function SomeComponent(props){
   const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(0)
   const iconRef = useRef(null)

   useEffect(() => {
      //always prints null
      console.log(iconRef.current) 
   }, [someState])

return <div>
 <button onClick={() => setSomeState(prev => prev + 1)}>{someState}</button>
 <Icon ref={iconRef}/>
</div>
}
```

The problem here is that iconRef will always return null. I think this is because it is declared as a component so the ref would need to be forwarded directly to the svg tags but how do I do that?

Any ideas?

Comment: If `someplace` is a `.svg` file this code should work, how you know the `ref` is always `null`? Do you have a reproducible example? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please show the `Icon` file, is it a component? If it does so your import is incorrect (probably).

Comment: @DennisVash yeah my bad. I updated the question with a reproducible working example

Comment: There is no problem in this code, please make a codesandbox demo

Comment: @DowenRobinson did you find a solution ? Could you post it ?

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74615135/11127541)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this works in `create-react-app`, but it is dead anyway.

First you need to install [svgr](https://react-svgr.com/).

`npm i @svgr/webpack`

Add a `svgr` config file.

`./.svgrrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  ref: true,
}
```

And a webpack config.

`webpack.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

If using `next` insert the webpack config in `next.config.js`.

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

Then you can do something like:

```
import Icon from "@icons/icon.svg";

const IconWithRef () => {
  const ref = useRef<SVGSVGElement | null>(null);

  return (
      <Icon width="50" ref={ref} />
  );
};
```

You can check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-with-ref-0346gz?file=/pages/index.tsx) for a working version.

**UPDATE**

Using this, I ran into some problems while using svg paths directly into `.css` files, because webpack resolves it as a react component. The workaround I could find to make both it work is by changing the `webpack` settings like so.

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        type: 'asset',
        resourceQuery: /url/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        resourceQuery: { not: [/url/] },
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

And then using `svg`'s paths in `.css` like:

```css
.svg-background {
  background-image: url('../path/to/svg/image.svg?url');
}
```

Notice the `?url` query param at the end.

Using the option `issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/`, like in the [docs](https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/#use-svg-in-css-files), did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This could be fixed in 3 steps:

1. Get the SVG icon as a React Component in your codebase.
2. Pass `setRef` to it.

Example:

Grab the SVG code into the component, like this:

```
const CloseIcon = (props) => (
  <svg
    width="38"
    height="38"
    viewBox="0 0 38 38"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <circle cx="19" cy="19" r="18" stroke="#AFAFAF" stroke-width="2"></circle>
    <path
      d="M13.0548 13.336L24.9868 25.9185"
      stroke="#AFAFAF"
      stroke-width="2"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="round"
    ></path>
    <path
      d="M24.9862 13.3365L13.0542 25.9189"
      stroke="#AFAFAF"
      stroke-width="2"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      stroke-linejoin="round"
    ></path>
  </svg>
)

export default CloseIcon
```

Then, in the Parent Component, where you use this icon, set its ref property, like:

```
...

const closeIconRef = createRef()
...

<CloseIcon
   style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 18, right: 18, cursor: 'pointer' }} 
   setRef={closeIconRef}
/>
```

Then add `setRef` to the  tag in your SVG component:

```
const CloseIcon = ({ setRef }) => (
  <svg
    ref={setRef}
    width="38"
    height="38"
    viewBox="0 0 38 38"
    fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
...
```

You are done!

**The important thing to remember: the child nodes still are non-referenced, so it works if there are no shapes on the way of a hit. You can attach a ref to every child tho.*

Comment: Looks like you should be [ref forwarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

Your answer doesn't actually address the code I've written. In my example I use [cra's method of importing svg](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs)

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood that you would like to import SVG exactly that way.
However, I also was considering cra's method at first. But then I found out that it is might be useful to create a component for passing different properties to it like, style, className etc.